# Drupal path alias routing to homepage (<front> page) when link is clicked in the main menu

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-path-aliases

I have been slaving over this issue for 6 hours now and it seems so simple but I can't seem to figure it out. I am creating a Drupal site for a client and I have never used Drupal before, Ive picked up on basic custom theming and everything was going well until I came across an error with path alias's.

I have booted up a new Drupal project to replicate the problem in its most basic form. I have an about us page running on the bartik theme, I have deleted all content. All I have is a basic page called About that is node/1. The main menu has one link in it that links to node/1. I have an alias for the page called "about".

PROBLEM:

When I click on the about link in the menu, the url displays localhost:8888/about, exactly what I want it to say however it just reloads the content of the initial homepage that I deleted. However if I type node/1 into the url bar or take the "about" alias away the page loads just as it should and displays the about content. I have tried flushing the page cache and that doesn't do anything. I have looked a plethora of tutorials on how to make page alias's and they all seem very straight forward, I can't seem to figure this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:
I installed the pathauto module and made the default pattern for all content aliases to be content/[node:title]. When I add a new alias like content/about it works fine but I still can't get just about to work with the pattern just [node:title].

Thanks,

Tyler

Comment: just to be sure, did you check /admin/config/search/path/list/about to see if there are multiple entries for the 'about' alias? That can happen but is wrong as you will never know where Drupal will lead the requests to.
Although if this is the case  I wouldn't know why it happened

Comment: @MerijnvanWouden Only the about alias is entered in when I navigate to that link.

Comment: Does anybody know whats going? I have booted it up on two different machines and I still can't get URL alises to load node content.

Comment: What you're trying to do is supposed to work so there is something irregular going on, this is why it surprises me that it happened to you twice on 2 different machines (both installations were done separately?). You might also check the default front page on /admin/config/system/site-information but I'm not sure if it will help you, I don't have another clue, just I think there is a misconfiguration somewhere. You could perhaps if it's allowed, put the website online and give login information so someone here can see what is wrong

Comment: @MerijnvanWouden I think I figured it out, it has something to do my apache configurations because I booted the site on my Dreamhost VPS and it worked perfect. However now I am stuck trying to figure out how to install the mod_rewrite module for apache.

Comment: right, strange though that rewriting does work for content/___ paths... apache should ship automatically with the mod_rewrite module unless perhaps you did a manual installation on windows?

Comment: I installed the laravel framework a couple months ago and I remembered doing some really weird things with my Apache configurations so I'm wondering if I changed something that I shouldn't have and now it's biting me in the butt. My main issue at this point is I uncommented the mod_rewrite module in the httpd.conf file but I can't seem to run the command to install it, I keep getting command not found.

Comment: perhaps you just need to restart apache, on debian: apachectl restart, redhat: service httpd restart

Comment: I tried apachectl restart and it didn't work, what does redhat: service httpd restart do?

Comment: those are commands on Linux OS of respectfully the Debian family and the Redhat family, I was just assuming you are running Apache on Linux but I don't know which OS you might be running on, might be even Windows

Comment: @MerijnvanWouden I am running OSX 10.9.5.